# Unity, Attempt to access method 'SFB.IStandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel' on type '' failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, file-browser, methodaccessexception

I'm using StandaloneFileBrowser package in order to load local 3d model to runtime. The file loading event is designed to be triggered by a button.
It works fine only in Unity if I click play. But after I built it and run the builded software, I've got "Not implemented: Class::FromIl2CppType" and "MethodAccessException: Attempt to access method 'SFB.IStandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel' on type '' failed."

Following are the code that execute the load.

```
string[] objPath = StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Select Folder", "", extensions, true);
FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader();
fileLoader.LoadObjFromFile(objPath[0]);
```

Then the code below will be called.

```
public void LoadObjFromFile(string objPath) {
    if (!File.Exists(objPath))
    {
        Debug.Log("File doesn't exist.");
    }else{
        if(loadedObject != null)            
            Destroy(loadedObject);
        loadedObject = new OBJLoader().Load(objPath);
    }
}
```

I have tried build with both windows and webgl, none of them worked.
I have googled about the problem and does not find similar issue.

Comment: Have you tried building it with MonoIL instead of IL2CPP?

Comment: The .NET scripting backend is deprecated and greyed out,  so it's not able to set it to MonoIL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275196/unity3d-cannot-change-scripting-backend-to-net

Comment: That's not true. It works on the latest Unity version and considering Mono was the initial compilation backend and IL2CPP was quite "new" in 2019 and not as stable and compatible as it is now. Try a newer Unity version and you'll see. The link you're referring is most likely something particular to UWP or whatever other exotic scenario. As you can see, it's included in the latest version of Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/Manual/Mono.html . Don't generalize particular cases :) Try it with Mono and let me know if the error is gone.